# No sound on Ubuntu 19.10 installed on HP Pavillion 24-XA0070A

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio

I come here in desperation after reading many online posts and trying a few different ways to fix this problem.

I purchased a new HP - PAVILION 24-XA0070A and installed Ubuntu 19.10. Everything worked fine except no sound. I only got sound when plugging speakers into the headphone jack, but that has subsequently stopped working thanks to my tinkering.

Online forums indicate the most likely cause is that the HDMI sound modules are blocking access to the builtin speakers. My most recent tweak was to add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
    # prevents speakers / analogue sound to work
blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi
```

It doesn't seem to work, because I rebooted and when I did this:

```
lsmod | grep snd_
```

I got this:

```
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    65536  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_hda_codec_realtek   114688  1
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               102400  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc,sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_nocodec        16384  1 snd_sof
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_skl           106496  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  2 sof_pci_dev,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,sof_pci_dev,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          241664  4 snd_sof_nocodec,snd_sof,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          49152  2
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    86016  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

Using pavucontrol I can see that the system can detect when I play audio. But nothing comes out of the speakers. I don't need to use HDMI output in any form whatsoever, so I'm fine with switching these kernel modules off. My understanding is that the NVIDIA card has audio which the kernel recognises, but that this somehow blocks access to the builtin speakers for sound output.

Some of my system info below:

```
sol@diamond:~$ uname -a
Linux diamond 5.3.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 8 20:14:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and this from `lspci -vv`:

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a3000000-a40fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a1ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at a44a4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a44a3000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at a4480000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at a449c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at a44a2000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device a375 (rev 10) (prog-if 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 84ee
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at a44a1000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
    Memory at a44a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company SATA Controller [RAID mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a4490000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at a449f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 6090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 6080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 6060 [size=32]
    Memory at a4400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a4300000-a43fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a4200000-a42fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: None
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company H370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10) (prog-if 80)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at a4498000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a4100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a449e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM108M [GeForce MX130]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at a4000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at a4304000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at a4300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at a4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I also have the same problem. Please, someone, help me out. I'm very frustated now.

Comment: As far as I can discover this is just the way Ubuntu is.  Welp.

Answer (score 4):

Run this command:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

After running this command I am able to see all output devices in the Settings menu & it solves the problem automatically.

This isn't a parmanent fix though.

I have GTX 970 on my desktop which provides display through HDMI port. Very often the output devices disappear from the option (& there is no sound) after I turn on the PC from suspension.

Comment: Worked for me. Is there a permanent fix? Interestingly on my machine the problem appeared after a clean install of 19.10, after that my upgraded system had developed boot problems. Before, even on 19.10 I never had this issue.

Comment: No permanent fix yet. Still I've to deal with this. If you get any fix please let us know. @drmat

Answer (score 4):

For me this bug started after the update to 5.3.0-42.34 kernel version.

The #3 answer in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061 solved my problem :

> This machine has dmic on it, so the legacy hda abort the probe:
>   snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, aborting probe
>
> And if want the legacy hda driver to work, please add options `snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
>
> This is a machine which has dmic on it, so please blacklist `snd_soc_skl` driver through `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, then the sof driver will be loaded.
>
> And if there is some issue, I will fix it, I am working on the the sof driver for eoan kernel now.

Answer (score 3):

You should go to **Settings → Sound → Output → Output Device** and try selecting a different output device (if you have not tried that already).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend that you **[edit]** this to expand it with information about why you think that may solve the problem described in the question here. I think it would also be useful to explain what readers should expect the Output Device settings to look like before they make the changes, and what the it should be changed to. (A screenshot might help to illustrate this.)

Answer (score 2):

I had a somewhat similar issue. I found that after updating to 19.10, I was not getting audio from headphones. After not finding any issue in pulse audio or alsamixer, I found that setting the input device to be the same port as the output device resolved the issue for me.

In other words, if you're using the *built-in speakers*, set input device as *built-in microphone*, and if you're using *built-in headphones*, set *built-in headset microphone* (even if the headphones don't have a microphone).

I'm not knowledgeable enough about the kernel to guess why this has happened, but I hope my experience at least helps you troubleshoot further if it's not able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue. After some tests I check and the sound is working, the problem is somewhere width the volume.
Using the 3.5 Jack ou built-in speaks, the volume is really too low, only in a silent space is possible to ear.
Using sound throw HDMI ou Bluethoot (in my case earbuds) the sound works perfectly.

In my case I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with 5.3.0-18-generic Kernel, I have the same problem width Ubuntu 18.04 after the last kernel upgrade.

Some extra info, I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad 530S

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from 18.04 to 19.10. In Settings it only shows a Test Output device and no real output devices.

It seems the drivers were loaded as with kernel 4.x. I found [snd-hda-intel only dummy output after upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/675670) which came to the conclusuion that timidity, a MIDI to WAV service was racing for the device.

I did this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge timidity timidity-daemon
```

This prompts you to confirm to remove `timidity` and `timidity-daemon` and if you do you should see real audio outputs in the settings after that if it is the same issue. If it was not you may reinstall with `sudo apt-get install timidity`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after an upgrade to 19.10

The symptoms were:

```
speaker-test -c 2 -D hw:1,0
```

worked (noise heard)

`aplay` gave no sound, but didn't show an error.

This helped:

I open the **System Settings**, went to

**multimedia > loudness > advanced** (3rd tab)

First I deactivated the HDMI device, then I set the second sound card to analog stereo duplex.

After that everything worked.

If that doesn't help get the `alsa-info.sh` from the alsa project on github to analyse the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had sound issues since upgrading to 19.10. Typically I can see all output devices, but no matter what I select there is no sound. Sometimes selecting and testing different outputs restores the sound. Until today rebooting always restored it. Sometimes this worked:

`pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

Today I noticed an update for alsa. Now after the update (including rebooting several times), I can still see all my output devices, but I get absolutely no sound on any of them. alsamixer shows 00 for all output devices and will not allow me to increase the volume. I can mute and unmute, but not increase. None of the old tricks have worked to restore sound.

I have two NVIDIA GPUs, an Onyx blackjack USB interface with a high end mic and headphone output, and a C922 Pro webcam that I sometimes use for input. The webcam mic seems to work fine for input. The Onyx input is no longer working, so there appear to be issues with both USB and HDMI audio devices.

Has anyone found a permanent solution to this? Is it best to just downgrade to last LTS? I had no problem with sound that version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, until about 10 mins ago...

I tried all the above under 19.10 on my HP Spectre x360, with a GEFORCE GTX installed. I could get Bluetooth to work - just - until a few days ago.

I am convinced this is an Ubuntu 19:10 issue on NVIDIA. I can dual boot this machine, so did so into W10. The system (using RealTek drivers) works fine but the default, out-of-the-box, Ubuntu 19:10 didn't. Recent updates appear to have managed to lose my Bluetooth devices.

Quite by chance,  I found [this itsfoss.com page](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

Having tried all their other tips I got to the last one which is intended for systems with 5.4 or less kernels ( I have 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64) ran:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

then:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

saved and closed the file, then shut down and re-started.

In line with [Aerkusa's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1188010/527764), I could now see my standard input and output devices. I configured things as that answer suggests and it works fine.

Comment: OK...an update. After a recent kernel upgrade the mike went again. Solution as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem after installing Ubuntu Studio 20.04 alongside Win10 on a refurbished HP Pro 6200 pc. I tried a few things from the answers to this question but that did not work.
But I have sound now from the onboard audio by disabling auto mute in alsamixer with my scroll wheel. (view: all (F5) )