# Output device is dummy output

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My sound used to work as expected but after some small update all I find now is "Dummy output" as my output device.
Below is the output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at a5518000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a5200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

but when running `alsamixer` I can only see the second one there

also running `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3` doesn't show the first intel driver. 
output:

```
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0949]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

sorry if my post isn't organized it's my first

Comment: I found this and it worked [Adding some boot parameter](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218063/1055428)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prb when I updated my software.
And the prb was the driver used  `Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl` is not correcte. I found the solution here : https://askubuntu.com/a/1217838/1058039

```
vim  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add in the end of file this line :

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0 in the
```

blacklist `snd_soc_skl` driver through balcklist.conf

```
sudo vim  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add in the end of this file this :

```
blacklist snd_soc_skl
```

Comment: The `blacklist snd_soc_skl` should probably go to `sudo vim  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a few days and I fixed it by referring the official PulseAudio documentation at

```
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/
```

The problem you've is in the PulseAudio layer, the

```
lspci
```

output shows that the audio hardware has been detected well by the system.

This was the part at

```
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Desktops/KDE/
```

that fixed my issue.

> One thing that can happen is that some other process "hogs" the audio
> device during PulseAudio startup. When this happens PA is unable to
> use the device until it is restarted. If PA is unable to open your
> hardware, you will automatically be given a "Dummy Output". As the
> name suggests, anything that is "Played" via this device is
> inaudible). This "Dummy Output" should be easily visible in both KMix
> and Phonon. If this happens, then you can debug which process is
> hogging the hardware via the command: sudo lsof /dev/snd/* /dev/dsp*
> (Note that apps which have the /dev/snd/control* devices open are
> unlikely to interfere).

I ran

```
lsof /dev/snd/*
```

to see that 'timidity' service had been hogging my sound card.  Since I didn't need it, I removed it:

```
sudo apt purge timidity
```

and as soon as it was removed, the audio volume in the system tray got unmuted and Armin van Burren blared through my speakers.

As a side note, this timidity package got installed as part of kde-full kali metapackage, and so I suggest not to install a package unless you need it and to avoid meta packages.